# Rails 4 strong params - using array in hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have seen a lot of samples of Rails code, and I saw two versions of nested attributes in strong params:

```
params.require(:smth).permit(:a, b: [])
params.require(:smth).permit(:a, { b: [] })
```

Why do I need to use braces in the second example? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Those 2 examples are identical - the braces around a hash are optional when it is the last argument to a method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have several hash in permit params you should separate by braces:

```
params.require(:smth).permit(:a, { b: [] }, { c: [] })
```

this should raise syntax error:

```
params.require(:smth).permit(:a,  b: [] , c: [] )
```

Comment: Thanks! It's pretty simple :)